# How to verify whether the IPTables rules are disabled?

Tags: linux, iptables

I am using Linux server and don’t have root access, used limited sudo access.

Version of Linux I am using is: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

I used this `lsmod` command to check if the ipTables are disabled below is the response:

```
$ lsmod | head -n 1; lsmod | grep ip
```

Output below:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nf_conntrack_ipv4       9506  22
nf_defrag_ipv4          1483  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_conntrack           80390  2 nf_conntrack_ipv4,xt_state
iptable_filter          2793  1
ip_tables              17831  1 iptable_filter
ipv6                  334740  0
ipt_REJECT              2351  0
```

With reference to the link [Redhat Linux link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/653393) even when the IPTables service is started or stopped there is no much difference in the `lsmod` command.

Is there a possibility to check the is the IPTables are disabled?

Also interested to know, will the IPTables without any chains & rules will still filter the request packets?

Is there any sniffing tool to check the incoming request before the IPTables and the what exactly the IPTables forwards to the application for processing?